# How to write the current date in the DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, razor, time

I am trying to pass the current date into a textbox, because the user can not enter values ​​in this field. And this will write to the DB. That way I'm doing, I can not write at the DB, since the field in the table is NULLABLE, this does not record. How can I do this?

```
@Html.TextBox("DATA_HORA", string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now), new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", Style = "width:100px;" })
```

Thank you all.

-- EDIT --

I'm using ADO.NET Entity Framework. The "Create" page was automatically generated when I created the Controller.

-- EDIT 2 --

My Controller:

```
namespace enChamados.Controllers
{ 
    public class ChamadosController : Controller
    {
        private enChamados_ModeloContainer db = new enChamados_ModeloContainer();

        //
        // GET: /Chamados/

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.CHAMADOS.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Chamados/Details/5

        public ViewResult Details(int? id)
        {
            CHAMADOS chamados = db.CHAMADOS.Find(id);
            return View(chamados);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Chamados/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        } 

        //
        // POST: /Chamados/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(CHAMADOS chamados)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.CHAMADOS.Add(chamados);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(chamados);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Chamados/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            CHAMADOS chamados = db.CHAMADOS.Find(id);
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Chamados/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(CHAMADOS chamados)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(chamados).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Chamados/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            CHAMADOS chamados = db.CHAMADOS.Find(id);
            return View(chamados);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Chamados/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {            
            CHAMADOS chamados = db.CHAMADOS.Find(id);
            db.CHAMADOS.Remove(chamados);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not clear how this UI element relates to the DB... can you clarify?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1665457.aspx

Comment: Sure. I'm using ADO.NET Entity Framework. The "Create" page was automatically generated when I created the Controller.

Comment: can you share your controller action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Brian P answered you can create an html editor for this field

Create a DateTime EditorTemplate (add a folder called EditorTemplates in Views\Shared folder) like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Nullable<System.DateTime>>" %>
<% if ( Model.HasValue )
   { %>
    <%: Html.TextBox( "" , String.Format( "{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}" , Model.Value )  )%>
<% }
   else
   { %>
   <%: Html.TextBox( "" , String.Format( "{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}" , DateTime.Now )  )%>
<% } %>
```

From your view use

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.nameOfYourField) %>
```

Comment: Hello Joan. I'm sorry, but I'm pretty new in ASP.NET MVC. I do not quite understand this solution.

In part that says "Create a DateTime EditorTemplate (add a folder called EditorTemplates in Views \ Shared folder) like this:" I need to create a new class or a new view in the Shared folder?

Comment: yes it's just a new view in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates,by inherits to `System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Nullable<System.DateTime>>` assuming your property is a nullable datetime.. or replace it if it's just by datetime if it's a datetime. by calling `EditorFor` methods, system knows where to find the editor template and apply it for your property

Comment: I'm sorry I could not do. I use Razor engine, and was complicated to me. Anyway, thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a date on the model that should not be changed, then you should *not* use a text field. Not only is there no reason to pass the information around in the view layer, but if the model binder has access to the field, it can potentially be changed. Even hidden, disabled or readonly fields can still be modified if you end-user knows how to use the development tools in their browser.

In your controller just set the date:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CHAMADOS chamados)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        chamados.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        db.CHAMADOS.Add(chamados);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(chamados);
}
```

Or for something like this where you're essentially setting a default value, it's usually easier to just set it up in your model:

```
private DateTime? createdDate = null;
public DateTime CreatedDate
{
    get { return createdDate ?? DateTime.Now; }
    set { createdDate = value; }
}
```

Then, you don't have to do anything in your controller. The CreatedDate will automatically be populated with the the current date and time when it's saved.